# Is it required to run AWS Glue crawler to detect new data before executing an ETL job?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

AWS Glue docs clearly states that Crawlers scrapes metadata information from the source (JDBS or s3) and populates Data Catalog (creates/updates DB and corresponding tables).

However, it's not clear whether we need to run a crawler regularly to detect new data in a source (ie, new objects on s3, new rows in db table) if we know that there no scheme/partitioning changes.

So, is it required to run a crawler prior to running an ETL job to be able to pick up a new data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AWS Glue will automatically detect new data in S3 buckets so long as it's within your existing folders (partitions).

If data is added to new folders (partitions), you need to reload your partitions using `MSCK REPAIR TABLE mytable;`.

Comment: It means if data is partitioned by date (year/month/day) and it comes continuously then before running a Glue job I have to run `MSCK REPAIR TABLE mytable;` at least once a day to be able to get latest data from a new 'day' folder. Is there a way to automate running the command (trigger)? Or invoke it from a Glue job script before processing?

Comment: I think probably a scheduled lambda may be the easiest way - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47546670/how-to-make-msck-repair-table-execute-automatically-in-aws-athena).  Another possibility is that you can use boto3 within the job running in Glue, so you should be able to use [this](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/athena.html#Athena.Client.start_query_execution) to execute the `MSCK REPAIR TABLE` command.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's very helpful! However, I started thinking about reading directly from s3 instead of Data Catalog in Glue job so that I always have the latest data without a need to run additional commands.

Comment: Yes, that's another good approach.  For raw /intermediate data we also often just use spark.read.csv or similar rather than bothering to load into catalog

Comment: Very useful answer @RobinL, does that mean if for example, crawler points to a folder (say, Parent folder) and this Parent has multiple subfolders (say abc, xyz,etc.), now if we add another subfolder (say, pqr) then would the file inside pqr subfolder be automatically detected by crawler (i.e without running it again)? thanks

Comment: @pc_pyr yes, so long as you run `MSCK REPAIR TABLE mytable;` to detect the new folder, and the schema of the file inside `pqr` is the same as the schema of the files inside `abc` `xyz` .

Comment: you can also schedule the glue crawler; https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-glue-crawler-schedule.html

Answer (score 0):

It's necessary to run the crawler prior to the job.

The crawler replaces Athena MSCK REPAIR TABLE and also updates the table with new columns as they're added.